How to create an open modelica model with a clickable button
I'm a teacher and I would like to ease user interaction in openmodelica simulation for my student (and me) !
For example, I would like to create a state graph model with a button to trigger state change. I would like to be possible to click on this button during the simulation, at any time to get the simulation more 'interactive'.
I went through documentation + google for hours, and couldn't find how to proceed.
Anyone could help please ? or provide any starting point for further investigations ?
Have a nice day !
